# Changing Camera Paths During Animation

Tags: camera, path

Is there currently any way to change the path that a camera is following during an animation? I'd like to be able to snap the camera to a new path at a set frame after it finishes following the first path. Is this possible, or do I have to make a new camera entirely?

Comment: Never tested this, but the *Follow Path* constraint has an *Influence* parameter. You can assign several of these to the same camera and control which one influences the object at a certain time by animating the *Influence* value